# Use OS X clipboard with zsh vi-mode

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-zle

I am using vi-mode with zsh at the moment. I am also using [this](https://github.com/alfredodeza/zsh-plugins/blob/master/vi/zle_vi_visual.zsh) to get a visual mode so I can include this in the right prompt.

I haven't yet been able to get this to work with OS X clipboard, pbcopy and pbpaste. I'd really like to be able to yank from visual mode, or from normal mode with yy and paste the contents into an email or a google search.

How do I do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: FYI The plugin you are using is quite old. `zsh` has built-in support for visual mode (as well as some other vim-style commands) since version 5.0.8 (May 2015). Although this does not solve the immediate problem, it might be easier to find/implement a solution based on built-in features.

Comment: I'm using zsh 5.3.1. The reason I have been using that plugin is that it gives me a KEYMAP value of vivis when I am in visual mode, which allows me to display 'VISUAL MODE' in the right prompt when I am in this mode. I wasn't able to do this using the visual mode built into zsh - I could get 'NORMAL MODE' to display, but not 'VISUAL MODE'.